# Can not get Registration ID in Emulator

Tags: android, kindle-fire, amazon-device-messaging

Hi I am running ADMMessenger sample application provided with SDK.

in which I am not able to get Registration ID in `register()` method of `MainActivity`.

Method is like this.

```
private void register()
{
    final ADM adm = new ADM(this);
    if (adm.isSupported())
    {
        if(adm.getRegistrationId() == null)
        {
            adm.startRegister();
        } else {

//                final MyServerMsgHandler srv = new MyServerMsgHandler();  
//                srv.registerAppInstance(getApplicationContext(), adm.getRegistrationId());
        }

        Log.v("log_tag","Reg_id:: "+adm.getRegistrationId());
    }
}
```

in Log cat I am always getting Reg_id:: null

and `onRegistrationError()` method of `SampleADMMessageHandler` is calling.

and error at there is `ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`

I can not understand what is problem, please help me.

Comment: how have you created your emulator image - is it a generic image, or are you using the Kindle Fire (ICS / 4.0.3) images? also have you logged in as a user in the emulator

Comment: Thanks! @Offbeatmammal I logged with amazon account and issue solved. and you can post this comment as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the service to work correctly you need to be using the Kindle image (not a generic Android one) and also make sure you have logged into your account on the device (pull down the status bar at the top and ensure you have selected an account)

Comment: Amazon no longer currently provides or supports a Kindle Fire emulator.  You must test on a physical device.